# How to reload a div with a widget inside by button click?

Tags: yii2, pjax

My controller

```
public function actionIndex()
{
        return $this->render('index');
}
```

In the view I call a series of widgets. All the logic inside the widgets, they do not have any input parameters. In each block for every widget I want to add a button to update the widget inside this block.

```
<?= Html::a("Обновить", ['???'], ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-default', 'data-pjax' => '#formsection']) ?>
```

I put widget in pjax

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'formsection', 'linkSelector' => '#chart a']); ?>
                <div class="chart" id="chart" style="height: 200px; position: relative;">
                    <?= Chart::widget(); ?>
                </div>
                <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

How to assign a specific block to a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand the chart is drawn via some values from the database which are frequently updated and you want those changes to be reflected in the chart when you click the reload button.

If the above is correct then you should use `$.pjax.reload` simply to reload the section bind the click event to the button

```
$this->registerJs('
    jQuery(document).on("click", "#my-button",  function(event){
            $.pjax.reload({container:"#formsection",timeout:1000})
          }
        );
');
```

Hope that helps.